# Default value for date in FreeMarker

Tags: java, postgresql, freemarker

I am generating an insert statements into Postgres using Freemarker template engine with the data coming from a csv file.  There's a date-typed columns in the DB (**'birthdate'**) for which the insert should contain a NULL in case the value is not present (to pacify Postgres) or the actual birthdate, if supplied.  Something like these:

```
INSERT INTO web_iws.broker (id,create_timestamp,update_timestamp,sfid,deleted,account_name,first_name,last_name,title,ssn,phone,mobile_phone,fax,email,mailing_street,mailing_city,mailing_state,mailing_postal_code,mailing_country,broker_number,npn,ga,ga_number,birthdate,appointed,indor_corp) VALUES(nextval('web_iws.broker_id_seq'::regclass),now(),now(),'003i00234597gnNAAQ',FALSE,'001i045681aYEiMAAW','Mason','Demarcove','Broker','','','','','mrdemarcove@abc.com','','','','','','BRN7J0943','','Savoy Associates','NJGA0306',NULL,'Appointed','');

INSERT INTO web_iws.broker (id,create_timestamp,update_timestamp,sfid,deleted,account_name,first_name,last_name,title,ssn,phone,mobile_phone,fax,email,mailing_street,mailing_city,mailing_state,mailing_postal_code,mailing_country,broker_number,npn,ga,ga_number,birthdate,appointed,indor_corp) VALUES(nextval('web_iws.broker_id_seq'::regclass),now(),now(),'003i07852RjON3sRN',FALSE,'001i0002'43567AAV','Maritza','Galsh','','145-98-1794','','','','marytza@galshben.com','718 River Road','Red Bank','NJ','07701','','BRNJ0877','7420702','Walsh Benefits','NJGA0008','1939-12-03','Appointed','Indv');
```

Is there in Freemarker something more elegant than this to express the above requirement:

```
"<#if birthdate?has_content>'${birthdate}',<#else>NULL,</#if>"
```

Perhaps a date built-in able to replace empty values with a configurable default or some kind of a ternary expression allowing to remove the if's...

Thank you in advance.

## Update

I tried the suggestions posted by @ddekany, here's what I see:

Random original data record (in csv) with empty birthday value (empty space between **NJGA0001,,Appointed**) looks like this:

```
2015-07-28T19:59:09.000Z,2015-07-28T19:59:15.000Z,003i000002oQSRMAA4,FALSE,Centerpoint Consulting,Briant,Hlonan,,,(973) 522-7886,,,briant@centerpointbenefits.com,,,,,,BRNJ0780,,BenefitMall,NJGA0001,,Appointed,Individual
```

When tried with:

```
"${birthdate?has_content?then(\"'${birthdate}'\", 'NULL')}"+
```

in my Java template, I'm getting an error:

```
11:52:37.168 [main] DEBUG util.BrokerInsertGeneratorTest - Error during saml template buildingfreemarker.core.ParseException: Error on line 1, column 672, in template insertProducingTemplate
Found then, expecting one of:  chunk,  is_date,  last,  root,  j_string,  contains,  is_hash,  long,  float,  ends_with,  namespace,  matches,  time,  values,  seq_last_index_of,  uncap_first,  byte,  substring,  is_transform,  web_safe,  groups,  seq_contains,  is_macro,  index_of,  word_list,  int,  is_method,  eval,  parent,  xml,  number,  capitalize,  if_exists,  rtf,  node_type,  double,  is_directive,  url,  size,  default,  is_boolean,  split,  node_name,  is_enumerable,  seq_index_of,  is_sequence,  sort,  is_node,  sort_by,  left_pad,  cap_first,  interpret,  children,  node_namespace,  chop_linebreak,  date,  short,  last_index_of,  is_collection,  ancestors,  length,  trim,  datetime,  is_string,  reverse,  c,  keys,  upper_case,  js_string,  has_content,  right_pad,  replace,  is_hash_ex,  new,  is_number,  is_indexable,  lower_case,  string,  exists,  html,  first,  starts_with
```

Using this expression:

```
"${(\"'${birthdate}',\")!'NULL'}"+
```

produces the following:

```
INSERT INTO web_iws.broker (id,create_timestamp,update_timestamp,sfid,deleted,account_name,first_name,last_name,title,ssn,phone,mobile_phone,fax,email,mailing_street,mailing_city,mailing_state,mailing_postal_code,mailing_country,broker_number,npn,ga,ga_number,birthdate,appointed,indor_corp) VALUES(nextval('web_iws.broker_id_seq'::regclass),now(),now(),'003i000002oQSRMAA4',FALSE,'Centerpoint Consulting','Briant','Hlonan','','','(973) 522-7886','','','briant@centerpointbenefits.com','','','','','','BRNJ0780','','BenefitMall','NJGA0001','','Appointed','Individual');
```

which is better as it creates **'NJGA0001','','Appointed'**, but won't be accepted by Postgres - it requires a NULL for an empty date field.

I'm open to hear other suggestions.

Here's the Java template string which works but requires less verbosity in handling its if statement:

```
public final static String templateStr = "INSERT INTO web_iws.broker (id,create_timestamp,update_timestamp,"
            + "sfid,deleted,account_name,first_name,last_name,title,ssn,phone,mobile_phone,fax,email,mailing_street,mailing_city,mailing_state,mailing_postal_code,mailing_country,broker_number,npn,ga,ga_number,birthdate,appointed,indor_corp) "+
 "VALUES(nextval('web_iws.broker_id_seq'::regclass),now(),now(),"+
"'${sfid}',"+
"${deleted},"+
"'${account_name}',"+
"'${first_name}',"+
"'${last_name}',"+
"'${title}',"+
"'${ssn}',"+
"'${phone}',"+
"'${mobile_phone}',"+
"'${fax}',"+
"'${email}',"+
"'${mailing_street}',"+
"'${mailing_city}',"+
"'${mailing_state}',"+
"'${mailing_postal_code}',"+
"'${mailing_country}',"+
"'${broker_number}',"+
"'${npn}',"+
"'${ga}',"+
"'${ga_number}',"+
"<#if birthdate?has_content>'${birthdate}',<#else>NULL,</#if>"+
"'${appointed}',"+
"'${indor_corp}');";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use postgres' `to_char` function. eg:

```
<#if birthdate?has_content>to_char('${birthdate}', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),<#else>NULL,</#if>
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no ternary operator, but there's an equivalent built-in:

```
${birthdate?has_content?then("'${birthdate}'", 'NULL')}
```

There's also a specialized operator to give defaults for missing values, like `someValue!defaultValue`. Your case is a bit tricky as you need to add those quotation marks, so it will be like:

```
${("'${birthdate}'")!'NULL'}
```

Also, know that an empty string doesn't count as missing for the `!` operator, unlike for `?has_content`.

Last not least, if you do this a lot, it may worth defining a `#function` for it.